# Entity Framework connecting to wrong database

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have an existing database and I'm trying to connect to it using entity framework, however it throws an exception saying

> The server principal "User" is not able to access the database
>   "DatabaseTwo" under the current security context.

However, I'm not trying to connect to DatabaseTwo, there is no reference to it anywhere in my entire solution.

**My DbContext:** (DatabaseOne)

```
Public Class MyContext
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("DatabaseOne")
    End Sub

    Public Property Objects As DbSet(Of Object)

End Class
```

**Web.Config connection string:**

```
<add name="DatabaseOne"
connectionString="server=myserver.com;database=DatabaseOne;UID=MyUser;PWD=MyPwd;
APP=MyApp;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

The other database does exist on the server and the user does have access to both database one and two, which is also strange consdering it says it dosen't have permission

Comment: Try debugging to figure out where it gets the other connection from

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen The context is being populated correctly, the database is "DatabaseOne"

Comment: Have you checked queries if any might explicit access DatabaseTwo?

Comment: Turns out it was trying to map the entity name to a table name that was slightly different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Entity had a slightly different name to the table, so using the attribute to specify the exact table name seemed to fix the problem. Still the exception was very strange

```
<Table("CorrectTableName")>
Public Class MyTable
    <Key>
    Public Property Id As Integer
End Class
```